# is there a way to flatten images in a list?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have 3  images, and i store them in a list C.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_images
datasets = load_sample_images()
image1 = [datasets.images[1][:,:,0],datasets.images[1][:,:,0],datasets.images[0][:,:,0]]
# datasets.images[1][:,:,0] is a Numpy array
```

For some reason, i want to flatten each of them. and stored  the result in a NumPy array.
My solution is

```
result = np.array([item.flatten() for item in image1])
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: What do you mean by better? You already have the format you want, what do you want to improve? The format itself? The performance of your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should know the size of an image. for example 32 * 32 if it is RGB then the shape would be (3 * 32 * 32 * 3) (first 3 is number of images and second 3 is for RGB color layers). Now need to apply first flatten() and then apply reshape() to the array:

```
  data = np.array([np.array(cv2.imread(imagePath[i])) for i in range(len(imagePath))] )

  output = x_data.flatten().reshape(3, 3072)
```